# Sort nested dictionary python 2.7, by deepest value, return key tuples

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, python-2.7

I have a dictionary like that:

```
d = {11:{'a':2.1, 'b':2.2,'c':3.0},
     12:{'b':4.5,'g':1.2},
     4:{'g':5.6,'a':4.5,'f':0.5,'r':1.3}
}
```

What I want to get is:

```
 [(4,'g'),(4,'a'),(12,'b'),(11,'c'),(11,'b'),(11,'a'),(4,'r'),(12,'g'),(4,'f')]
```

So I want to do is sort in descending order the values and get the dictionary keys, that realize this order.

I would like to use `key = lambda x, y: d[x][y]` something, but I don't know how to return a list I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
sorted(((k1, k2) for k1 in d for k2 in d[k1]), key=lambda t: d[t[0]][t[1]], reverse=True)
```

The generator expression lists all key 'paths' to the values first, then sorts those on the value, reversed.

Demo:

```
>>> sorted(((k1, k2) for k1 in d for k2 in d[k1]), key=lambda t: d[t[0]][t[1]], reverse=True)
[(4, 'g'), (4, 'a'), (12, 'b'), (11, 'c'), (11, 'b'), (11, 'a'), (4, 'r'), (12, 'g'), (4, 'f')]
```